# RevokePermissionListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, facebook

Why my eclipse is showing me this error ? I am trying to implement the facebook APi for android but it gives me the above error why ?

They have mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#token) to place this for logout.
This is the code.

```
String method = "DELETE";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
/*
* this will revoke 'publish_stream' permission
* Note: If you don't specify a permission then this will de-authorize the application completely.
*/
params.putString("permission", "publish_stream");
mAsyncRunner.request("/me/permissions", params, method, new RevokePermissionListener(), null);
```

I placed it in the `onComplete` function of `mAsyncRunner.logout`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the class `RevokePermissionListener` which implements `AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener()`.  In the same file, add the following code:

```
public class RevokePermissionListener implements AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```